# how to set width of a richfaces calendar?

Tags: calendar, richfaces

I am trying to set the width for *richfaces* calendar, using `style="width:60px"`, but it's not working.

```html
<rich:calendar  id="givenDate" name="givenDate" 
    enableManualInput="true" style="width:60px" 
    datePattern="MM/dd/yyyy"  value="#{shotController.adminDate}" 
    immediate = "true"  required="true" 
    requiredMessage="#{msg.requiredmsg}" popup="true" />
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 10):

The `<rich:calendar>` tag component is a composition of many components and you can set the style of each one. For the input, you should use the `inputStyle` property, or the `inputClass` for a CSS defined class:

```html
<rich:calendar id="givenDate" name="givenDate"
    enableManualInput="true"
    <!-- this will be the style for the input textbox -->
    inputStyle="width:60px"
    datePattern="MM/dd/yyyy" value="#{shotController.adminDate}"
    immediate = "true" required="true"
    requiredMessage="#{msg.requiredmsg}" popup="true" />
```

Another solution might be rewriting the CSS styles for the specific calendar component. The full list can be found in the [RichFaces Component appendix A: Style classes](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_2_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html/appe-Developer_Guide-Style_classes_and_skin_parameters.html#sect-Developer_Guide-Style_classes_and_skin_parameters-richcalendar).

More info:

- [RichFaces Calendar Component](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_2_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Rich_inputs.html#sect-Component_Reference-Rich_inputs-richcalendar)

Comment: i tried both inputStyle and inputClass, seems like the value is not taken. I looked at the RF style class calendar section, it doesn't have width parameter there.

Comment: Which of the inner component of the calendar you need to set the size: the input, the popup...?

Comment: inputStyle atribute works fine, did you try CTRL+SHIFT+R to refresh the styles?

Comment: I have the same problem, but I want to set the size of the popup. I tried with style="width:300px" (as in the showcase) but it doesn't work... If I look with firebug, the element style _width_ is not listed/set.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is still looking for an answer : To set the size of the input textbox the " inputSize" attribute can be used. For Example

```
 inputSize="10"
```

This will set the size the text box to 10 characters length.

reference: https://community.jboss.org/thread/8802